# Was it possible to wield more than one Ring of Power?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

The One Ring controlled 19 other rings, with some mighty person wielding each.  As [The One Wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Rings_of_Power) describes, the rings for Men and Dwarves had fairly uniform powers, but the Elves' rings - Narya, Nenya, and Vilya - each had their own particular specialty.

Would it have been possible for someone to gather and wield all three at once, thus becoming that much more powerful?  Is there any evidence to that, whether from direct mention by Tolkien, or via mention of someone's temptation to possess all three?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Celebrimbor originally gave both Vilya and Narya to Gil-Galad.  It is possible he wore both for a little while, though the Elven rings went unused after Sauron made the One and by the time they were used again Gil-Galad was dead and those rings were split between Elrond and Cirdan.  Other than that possibility there is no mention of considering one person wearing more than one ring at a time (other than Sauron, who took back three of the Dwarven rings and may have been the one actually wearing the Nine in the end).

Comment: Good point, although I'd make the subtle distinction between *wearing* more than one ring at a time, and actually *wielding* them.  If it's possible to *wield* more than one, and to be more powerful for it, it creates a slightly different dynamic among each wielder - one of both having power, but also one of fighting the temptation to become more powerful by acquiring the other two.